# Issues while using script (typescript) command with rksh restricted ksh

Tags: unix, logging, ksh, aix

I have a scenario where I want to log every activity for a particular user. I have a script built around the script command which I invoke from the user's .profile. Now the requirement is that the user should not be able to delete the subsequent typescript file that is created. Towards that, I've created a user with the default shell of rksh and put a restriction on commands that can wipe the file out. But the problem is that when I login with that user, if I call the script with the script command, the forked shell is always sh and not rksh. I know that if SHELL is not set, then the forked shell will be /bin/sh by default, but I have SHELL setup properly. How do I ensure that the forked shell is rksh only?

If I comment out the call to the logger from .profile, then I get a rksh shell. But even then if I manually issue the script command, it launches sh. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Of the top of my head, it sounds like a bug.

Comment: Seems that way to me as well. I setup a .kshrc file which explicitly sets and exports SHELL but no luck.

Comment: What level of AIX?  What exactly is SHELL set to?  Is it an absolute path?  Last, check at the bottom of /etc/security/login.cfg.  There is a line: shells = /bin/sh,.....  Make sure that your exact path is listed in that list.

Comment: I'm on AIX 6.1. SHELL is set to /usr/bin/rksh. The login.cfg does have the absolute path listed in usw.

Comment: I was trying to compile a solaris script.c from the O'Reilly example code but it seems that AIX does not like ioctl i_push ptem. I'm not well versed with system programming, any ideas how to get it to work? I ask because if I can get this to compile and work properly then I can edit script.c and change default shell to rksh.

Comment: AIX auto pushes the needed modules.  Try removing that ioctl completely and see if that works.